# Not able to run multi node cluster on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra

Trying to configure 3 nodes in Cassandra on AWS EC2 (have set ICMP, SSH, HTTP and HTTPS in security groups accordingly)

Cluster name is also set as same in all the three cassandra.yaml file i.e. 'Test Cluster'

Mentioned there corresponding ip as example for node1
listen_address: node1 
seeds:  "node1,node2,node3"
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
broadcast_rpc_address: 1.2.3.4

Machines are able to ping each other, using the IP obtained by ifconfig.

But when I run cassandra on the three mentioned machine I get

INFO  08:33:52 No gossip backlog; proceeding.
cassandra 2.2.3
Machine Ubuntu

Is something I am missing?

Comment: You've pasted one line, and it's not indicating any sort of error. What makes you think that Cassandra isn't running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although you've posted very little, it might be your snitch. Use GossipingPropertyFileSnitch or Ec2Snitch. Also, you shouldn't make every node a seed. In a 3-node cluster you need only 1 or maybe 2 for redundancy. The seeds: list in cassandra.yaml should be the same on each node. You shouldn't set both the rpc_address and the broadcast_rpc_address. Pick one or the other.